# Cumulative Distribution Function CDF of a Random Variable please check

Tags: probability

Let $X$ be a random variable with cumulative distribution function $F$. Let $G=\sqrt{F}$. Is $G$ necessarily the cumulative distribution function of some random variable? Please explain why or why not.

My Work:

Let $X$ be a random variable with CDF $F$. Let $G=\sqrt{F}$.
We know $F_X(x)=P(X \leq x)$ for $-\infty < x< \infty$.

i).  $F_X(-\infty)=\lim_{x\rightarrow -\infty}F_X(x)=0$

ii).  $F_X(\infty)=\lim_{x\rightarrow \infty}F_X(x)=1$

iii) $F_X(x)$ is a nondecreasing function of $x$.

thus . $G_X=\sqrt{F_X(x)}$

$\lim_{x\rightarrow -\infty} G_X(x)=\sqrt{F_X(-\infty)}=\lim_{x\rightarrow -\infty}\sqrt{F_X(x)}=\sqrt{\lim_{x\rightarrow -\infty}F_X(x)}=\sqrt{0}=0$

$\lim_{x\rightarrow \infty} G_X(x)=\sqrt{F_X(\infty)}=\lim_{x\rightarrow \infty}\sqrt{F_X(x)}=\sqrt{\lim_{x\rightarrow \infty}F_X(x)}=\sqrt{1}=1$

If $F_X(x)$ is a nondecreasing function then since $\sqrt{()}$ is an increasing function, then $G$ is a non decreasing function.

Thus yes, $G$ is necessarily a cumulative distribution function of some random variable.

THANK YOU for your help.

Comment: You should also check that $G$ is càdlàg.

Comment: Ah, if $F$ is càdlàg and so is the sqrt function then does it follow that $G$ is càdlàg as well?